# How to display byte array hex values?

Tags: c#, file, hex, arrays

Hi i am making application in c#.I have byte array of containing hex values.I want to to write that values as it is in file without converting it into string or anything else.Please help me.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't avoid converting it to a string if you want to display it. You can use:

```
String.Format("{0,10:X}", hexValue)
```

Answer (score 27):

I'm a bit late but nobody mentioned the [BitConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) class that does a little magic for you.

```
public static string GetHexStringFrom(byte[] byteArray)
{
  return  BitConverter.ToString(byteArray); //To convert the whole array
}
```

Also, there are overloads that can help parse only a part of the array

Comment: Note that BitConverter adds "-" marks in between the bytes. Make sure to remove those if you don't want them :)