# C# equivelant to Java Arrays.ToString(byte[])

Tags: c#, java, arrays

Is there an equivalent method in `C#` to the Java method `Arrays.ToString(byte[])`

Found [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString%28byte%5B%5D%29)

Essentially I want to convert a byte array to a string of the format:

`"[10, 23, 0, 15]"`

The numbers reflecting the value of each byte in the byte array.

Comment: possible duplicate of [byte\[\] to string in c#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1003275/byte-to-string-in-c-sharp)

Comment: I don't think that method returns a string in the format that I'm after, using that method I get a string of characters looking something like this "����\0JFIF\0\0`\0`\0\0��\0C\0"

Comment: @BillyPownall What are the input value and output result look like?

Comment: Oh I see, close-vote retracted. Here's the new duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8238755/how-to-display-byte-array-hex-values

Comment: [This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3a733s97.aspx) will get you hyphen-separated hex output, if that's ok.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a one-liner. Try this:

```
static string Array2String<T>( IEnumerable<T> list )
{
  return "[" + string.Join(",",list) + "]";
}
```

You might need to tweak it a bit for different flavors of `T` to allow for proper quoting and/or stringification<sup>**1**</sup> etc., but that's the general principle.

<sup>**1**</sup> Not all types have a `ToString()` that comes back with anything terribly useful since `object` just hands back the type name.